# Saber valor da CheckBox dentro de uma MultiView/View/DataList

Tags: asp, checkbox, view, value

Gostaria de saber como poderia terminar o valor de uma `checkbox` que por sua vez está dentro de uma `DataList` que está inserida dentro de uma `View` e esta última dentro de uma `MultiView`.

Tentei alguns métodos `FindControl` mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Como você tentou quando fez pelo FindControl?

Comment: @Maicon Carraro 
`CheckBox cb = FindControl("ckBoxStock") as CheckBox;
LinkButton lb = FindControl("linkBtnAddCart") as LinkButton;

if (cb.Checked != true)
{

    lb.Enabled = false;

}`

Comment: Desta forma testei mas sem sucesso.

`foreach (DataListItem item in DataListProdutosGridView.Items)
            {
                CheckBox ckBoxStock = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("ckBoxStock");
                LinkButton linkBtnAddCart = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("linkBtnAddCart");
                if (ckBoxStock.Checked)
                {
                    linkBtnAddCart.Enabled = true;
                }

                else

                {
                    linkBtnAddCart.Enabled = false;
                }
            }`

Comment: Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Experimenta colocar `var cb = SuaMultiView.FindControl("ckBoxStock") as CheckBox;`